# How to send basic.ack to Queue from message handler in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

In RabbitMQ api, when `auto-ack` is set to false on a channel, we can use `channel.basicAck(...)` to send acknowledgement back to the queue.

In Spring, I have a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` where I set `AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL`. and handler (`SomeMessageHandler` that handles a String type) I set as the listener for the `MessageListenerAdapter`.  I can't find anywhere (any component) where I send the acknowledgement back to the queue. Is there a component I need to autowire to my handler to take care of this? Or what is the the correct way to handle this acknowledgement, when acknowledgment mode is set to manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using MANUAL acks, you can't use the `MessageListenerAdapter`, you have to implement `ChannelAwareMessageListener`. However, MANUAL ack is rarely needed with Spring AMQP, the container will take care of it for you on success (or reject on failure) when the delivery completes (or is handed off to another thread).